# Android: Broadcast Receiver and Service issues

Tags: android, service, android-intent, broadcast

I have written a simple activity to test out services and broacast receivers and a service to go along with it. In order to know whether or not it's working I've set up a Toast within the main activity to be showed once the OnReceive() method is called. But for the life of me I can't get this to work.

These are the codes:

public class ServicesAndBroadcastIntentActivity extends Activity {

```
private Toast test;
private Intent intent;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    intent = new Intent(this,serviceD.class);
    test = Toast.makeText(this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    test.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        test.setText((intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MSG")));
        test.show();
    }
};


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    startService(intent);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(serviceD.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    stopService(intent);        
}
```

}

public class serviceD extends Service{

```
private Intent intent;
static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.mejg.ServicesAndBroadcastIntent";

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
}

public void onStart(){
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MSG","hola");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `startService()` before `registerReceiver()`. Both are asynchronous operations, but they will still likely occur in sequence. Hence, `onStart()` of your service will be called before `registerReceiver()` does its work, which means your broadcast goes out before your receiver is set up.

For this sort of experimentation, I recommend setting up a basic UI (e.g., one really big button) and doing the `startService()` call when the button is pressed.

Also, since the service calls `stopSelf()`, you do not need to call `stopService()` from the activity.

Also also, you might consider using `LocalBroadcastManager` for this -- same basic syntax with better performance and security, since it all stays within your process.

**UPDATE**

Also also also, `onStart()` has been deprecated for two-plus years, and your method signature for it is wrong, anyway. Please use `onStartCommand()`, with the right parameters.

Also also also also, use `@Override` when overriding methods, to help you catch these sorts of problems.

Comment: I did what you suggested, starting the service from a button and registering the receiver before starting the service, and it does not seem to work still. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @rodkarom: Not off the top of my head. FWIW, here's a sample use of `LocalBroadcastManager` with an almost identical setup to yours (though I use a `TextView` instead of a `Toast`). You might temporarily get rid of `setGravity()` to simplify the `Toast`, in case that's somehow messed up -- I rarely change my `Toast` gravity.

Comment: One more doubt... Do I need to declare an intent-filter in my AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @rodkarom: Not when you are using `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I may have figured it out. I used Log.d to log when the OnCreate and OnStart methods of the service are called and the OnStart method is never called. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @rodkarom: Sorry, I totally missed your problems with `onStart()`, though I should have seen them. See my update to the answer.

Comment: @rodkarom: Yes. BTW, I forgot to actually include the link to the sample I mentioned earlier: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Local